# ng2-smart-table on click row should highlighted

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng2-smart-table

i have already tried to solve the issue but not able to highlight row on click event.

```html
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settingsPatient" [source]="sourcePatient" (userRowSelect)="patientStudy($event)" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)">"

</ng2-smart-table>
```

i am using angular 7 and when i click on any row in ng2-smart-table row not get highlighted e.g change colour of of row when i clicked on it.

this is my function for row click event-(userRowSelect)="patientStudy($event)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a row is selected, 'selected' class is being added to it... this is where we can style the row using:

```
::ng-deep tbody  tr.ng2-smart-row.selected
{ background:lightblue !important; border:1px solid blue;}
```

[working stackblitz is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqmlnn)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`::ng-deep .nb-theme-default ng2-smart-table tbody tr.selected, .nb-theme-default ng2-smart-table tbody tr:hover { background: rgb(34, 151, 190) !important; border:1px solid blue; }`